# web page google map share on whatsapp

Tags: php, jquery, html, google-maps, whatsapp

I am displaying a google map on my mobile website. I want to add a **share with whatsapp button** to share the google map on all mobile whatsapp. I tried it in many ways but, i am not able to share the map on whatsapp. I am only able to share the map link but not to share map itself.

i tried:

```
<a href="whatsapp://send?text=http://map.google.com" data-action="share/whatsapp/share">Share via Whatsapp</a>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- Go to Google Maps: https://www.google.com/maps/
- Search for the
  location you want to share
- Click on the location once
- Copy the URL
  displayed in your browser address bar OR Click on the share icon on
  the left to open the share page.
- Share this URL (eg:
  https://www.google.co.in/maps/place/Kohima+World+War+II+Cemetery/@25.6676467,94.1031367,19z/data=!4m2!3m1!1s0x0:0x233cb3f9fffddf78)

You can share this URL via
   Whatsapp like this-

```
<a href="whatsapp://send?text=https://www.google.co.in/maps/place/Kohima+World+War+II+Cemetery/@25.6676467,94.1031367,19z/data=!4m2!3m1!1s0x0:0x233cb3f9fffddf78" data-action="share/whatsapp/share">Share via Whatsapp</a>
```

Comment: thanks for response. i tried it but it is just display as link whatsapp. i need to display google map like we are sharing location on whatsapp

Comment: @CodeEmbassy, you can't. whatsapp:// is limited to share files or messages. https://faq.whatsapp.com/iphone/23559013

Comment: @ocanal  is there not nay way that we can pass just lat and long and it get map from our mobile and share that map to whatsapp ?

Comment: If it was possible google maps could handle that whe you share an address from google maps to whatsapp. This is what happen when you share an address for whatsapp on google maps app. https://i.imgur.com/PfWaZqu.png